# How to display multiple inline images in email body when we are sending mail with dynamic content using phpMailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm trying to send HTML mail, with PHPMailer, with images. The body is loaded or copied from a html file, that contains all the info.

So how can i  find inline images dynamicaly from body and apply AddEmbeddedImage() method to it.

PHP Code

```
  $mail->addReplyTo($from, $fromName);
    $mail->addBCC($from);
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->Body = $body;
    $mail->AddEmbeddedImage($filepath, $filecid, $filename);
   if(!$mail->send()) 
            {
                echo "Failed To Send Mail";
                exit;
            } 
            else
            {
                echo "Mail Has Been Sent";
                exit;

            }
```

Comment: In the body from the HTML file, do you have markup with PHP Mailer CIDs `<img src="cid:my-attach">` or rather `<img src="./actual/path/to/file1.jpg">`?

Comment: Yes i have  PHP Mailer CIDs <img src="cid:my-attach">...

Comment: You can loop through all images easily if the cid 'my-attach' always matches 'my-attach.jpg' or 'my-attach.png' and the files are all located in the same folder, is this what you want? Or are images not always named after the cid and file location?

Comment: Yes through this way receiver can view images of mail content of inbox but  
how can i display images in mail content of sent box at sender side.

Comment: Ohhh a preview for yourself (like before sending)

Comment: No, but like after sending a mail. When i go through list of sent mails from my sentBox

Comment: Before/after but in browser

Comment: Sorry for late reply....Yes i want  a view of mail in browser...

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the file path associated with every cid, we need a list of cids related to the image source.

```
<?php

    // Create associative array for images
    // Relation syntax: cid => filename
    $images = array(
        'file-1' => './src/file-1.png',
        'file-2' => './src/file-2.png',
        'file-3' => './src/file-3.png'
    );

    // Retrieve the body contents
    $body = file_get_contents('src/body.html');
```

Next, fetch all images with `preg_replace_callback` to be able to treat every image source differently.
Use the anonymous function `function($matches)` in combination with the `use ($images)` closure. This way we have `$images` available inside the `preg_replace_callback`.

```
    // Create body
    $body = preg_replace_callback(

        // Regex for finding image sources
        '/<img(.*?)src=[\'|\"](.*?)[\'|\"](|.*?)>/',

        // Callback
        function($matches) use ($images){

            // For rebuilding the <img> tag
            $beforeImageSRC = $matches[1];
            $afterImageSRC  = $matches[3];

            // Image source
            $imageSRC       = $matches[2];
```

Then, validate if the source found is actually a PHPMailer cid. Also check if found cid exists in our `$images` array.

```
            // Is this source a PHPMailer cid?
            if(preg_match('/^cid:/', $imageSRC)){

                $fileCID    = preg_replace('/^cid:/', '', $imageSRC);

                // Does the cid exist in our associative array?
                if(isset($images[$fileCID])){

                    // Update image source if we have it listed in array
                    $imageSRC = $images[$fileCID];

                }

            }
```

Finally, rebuild and return the image tag to the body and print the body to preview the output in your browser.

```
            return '<img' . $beforeImageSRC . 'src="' . $imageSRC . '"' . $afterImageSRC . '>';
        },
        $body);

    print $body;

?>
```